# mySQL Tables Query with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have four tables as follows:

**1. wmu_kpi_cateogries:** (*Table with KPIs Category*)

- category_id
- category_title
- isvalid

> Data: Contains 5 KPI Categories

**2. wmu_kpi_subcategories:** (*Table with KPIs Sub-Cateogry*)

- Subcategory_id
- Subcategory_title
- category_id
- isvalid

> Data: Contains 4 KPI Sub-Categories for the KPI Category with category_id 1,2 and 3. The KPI category with 4 and 5 has 3 and 6 sub-categories respectively.

**3. wmu_designations** (*Table with Designations in the Company*)

- designation_id
- designation_title
- section_id

> Data: Contains 10 designation

**4. wmu_designation_to_kpis** (*Table that is filled when applying KPI values to each designation*)

- empkpi_id
- designation_id
- category_id
- subcategory_id
- target_value

> Data: The table that the form fills while allocating the kpi cateogires and sub-categories value respectively to each designation.

How do I write a single query that can display names of each category and sub category per designation title along with their values?

SAMPLE DATA FOR EACH TABLE

"category_id"   "category_title"    "category_description"  "isvalid"   "category_year"
"1" "Financial" ""  "1" "2013"
"2" "Growth"    ""  "1" "2013"
"3" "Risk"  ""  "1" "2013"
"4" "Service Quality"   ""  "1" "2013"
"5" "People"    ""  "1" "2013"

---

"subcategory_id"    "subcategory_title" "subcategory_description"   "category_id"   "isvalid"
"1" "AM: Up Front Fees (SR)"    "0" "1" "1"
"2" "AM: Up Front Fees Team Target Achievement" "0" "1" "1"
"3" "Brokerage: Net Commission Contribution (50% of RC Target) (%)" "0" "1" "1"
"4" "Brokerage: Net Commission Contribution Team Target Achievement"    "0" "1" "1"
"5" "IB: Management Fees Contribution (%)"  "0" "1" "1"
"6" "AM: Net Sales Ratio (SR) = Subscriptions / Redemptions"    "0" "2" "1"
"7" "AM: Deals Closed (#)=  # of New Subscriptions" "0" "2" "1"
"8" "Brokerage: Client Base Increment:  New Clients + Reactivated Clients (#)"  "0" "2" "1"
"9" "AM + Brokerage: New HNW Clients Retention # of New HNW Clients (Balance >2M) / # of Lost/Transferred HNW Clients (Balance=0)"  "0" "2" "1"
"10"    "AM + Brokerage: RB Contribution: Success Deals / # of Joint visit with RB" "0" "2" "1"
"11"    "New Segmented Clients (#) 1 in +100 M (Semi-Annually per Region) 3 in 20-100 M (Semi-Annually per Region) 5 in 2-20 M (Semi-Annually per Region) Total = 18 per Region, 54 Overall"    "0" "2" "1"
"12"    "Compliance Violations (#)" "0" "3" "1"
"13"    "High Risk Past Due Audit Exceptions (#)"   "0" "3" "1"
"14"    "High Priority Quality Comments on Investment Centers (#)"  "0" "4" "1"
"15"    "Reduction in WM Related Complaints (%)"    "0" "4" "1"
"16"    "Call Reports for HNW Clients (Balance >=2 M) (#) 2 visits to clients +100 M (Annually per IA/IO) 2 visits to clients 20-100 M (Annually per IA/IO) 1 visits to clients 2-20 M (Annually per IA/IO)"    "0" "4" "1"
"17"    "# of visits to different clients (2 per day per IA/IO)"    "0" "4" "1"
"18"    "# of HNW Clients (Balance >=2 M) / # of IAs/IOs"   "0" "5" "1"
"19"    "# of IAs and IOs Staff / # of Investment Centers"  "0" "5" "0"
"20"    "# of Center Managers, CSOs and Brokers Staff / # of Investment Centers"    "0" "5" "1"
"21"    "Staff Meeting by Region/Area Visit 2 Annually (#)" "0" "5" "1"
"22"    "Joint Visit with Different IAs/IOs (3 per Week) (#)"   "0" "5" "1"
"23"    "Visits to Different Centers (3 per Week) (#)"  "0" "5" "1"
"24"    "Training Against Plan (%)" "0" "5" "1"
"25"    "Leadership Competency (#)" "0" "5" "1"

---

"designation_id"    "designation_title" "designation_description"   "section_id"    "isvalid"   "issales"
"1" "Wealth Management Head"    ""  "1" "1" "1"
"2" "Advisory Head" ""  "1" "1" "1"
"3" "Advisory Regional Manager" ""  "1" "1" "1"
"4" "IA/IO" ""  "1" "1" "1"
"5" "Centers Head"  ""  "1" "1" "1"
"6" "Centers Regional Manager"  ""  "1" "1" "1"
"7" "Center Manager"    ""  "1" "1" "1"
"8" "CSO"   ""  "1" "1" "1"
"9" "Broker"    ""  "1" "1" "1"

---

"empkpi_id" "type_id"   "employee_id"   "designation_id"    "category_id"   "subcategory_id"    "target_value"  "kpi_year"
"1" "1" "0" "1" "1" "0" "25"    "2013"
"2" "1" "0" "1" "1" "0" "50"    "2013"
"3" "1" "0" "1" "1" "0" "0" "2013"
"4" "1" "0" "1" "1" "0" "40"    "2013"
"5" "1" "0" "1" "1" "0" "0" "2013"
"6" "1" "0" "1" "1" "0" "10"    "2013"
"7" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "2013"
"8" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "2013"
"9" "1" "0" "1" "2" "0" "25"    "2013"
"10"    "1" "0" "1" "2" "0" "20"    "2013"
"11"    "1" "0" "1" "2" "0" "20"    "2013"
"12"    "1" "0" "1" "2" "0" "20"    "2013"
"13"    "1" "0" "1" "2" "0" "20"    "2013"
"14"    "1" "0" "1" "2" "0" "20"    "2013"
"15"    "1" "0" "1" "2" "0" "0" "2013"
"16"    "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "2013"
"17"    "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "2013"
"18"    "1" "0" "1" "3" "0" "15"    "2013"
"19"    "1" "0" "1" "3" "0" "50"    "2013"
"20"    "1" "0" "1" "3" "0" "50"    "2013"
"21"    "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "2013"
"22"    "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "2013"
"23"    "1" "0" "1" "4" "0" "20"    "2013"
"24"    "1" "0" "1" "4" "0" "50"    "2013"
"25"    "1" "0" "1" "4" "0" "50"    "2013"
"26"    "1" "0" "1" "4" "0" "0" "2013"
"27"    "1" "0" "1" "4" "0" "0" "2013"
"28"    "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "2013"
"29"    "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "2013"
"30"    "1" "0" "1" "5" "0" "15"    "2013"
"31"    "1" "0" "1" "5" "0" "20"    "2013"
"32"    "1" "0" "1" "5" "0" "20"    "2013"
"33"    "1" "0" "1" "5" "0" "20"    "2013"
"34"    "1" "0" "1" "5" "0" "0" "2013"
"35"    "1" "0" "1" "5" "0" "0" "2013"
"36"    "1" "0" "1" "5" "0" "0" "2013"
"37"    "1" "0" "1" "5" "0" "20"    "2013"
"38"    "1" "0" "1" "5" "0" "20"    "2013"
"39"    "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "2013"
"40"    "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "2013"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all fields on table `wmu_designation_to_kpis` are *NON-NULLABLE*, an `INNER JOIN` for each tables will do. However, if some fields are *NULLABLE*, change `INNER JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.empkpi_id,
        b.designation_title,
        c.category_title,
        d.Subcategory_title,
        a.target_value
FROM    wmu_designation_to_kpis a
        INNER JOIN wmu_designations b
            ON a.designation_id = b.designation_id
        INNER JOIN wmu_kpi_cateogries c
            ON a.category_id = c.category_id
        INNER JOIN wmu_kpi_subcategories d
            ON a.subcategory_id = d.subcategory_id
```

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works with the LEFT JOIN as the fields are NULLABLE. But the issue is that the sub-categories names are not appearing. Can you please shed some light on that?

Comment: maybe the sample records can be pasted along with the question or on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: I have pasted the sample data along with the question. Please take a look if it makes sense.